# Why this code works in interactive but fails when compiled?

Tags: ocaml

I'm a complete newbie in OCaml and trying to create a simple console program.

```
(*let k = read_int()
let l = read_int()
let m = read_int()
let n = read_int()
let d = read_int()*)

let k = 5
let l = 2
let m = 3
let n = 4
let d = 42

let rec total: int -> int -> int = fun i acc ->
  if i > d then
    acc
  else
    if (i mod k) == 0 || (i mod l) == 0 || (i mod m) == 0 || (i mod n) == 0 then
      total (i + 1) (acc + 1)
    else
      total (i + 1) acc;

print_int (total 1 0)
```

But if I try to compile it, it fails:

```
PS C:\Users\user> ocamlc -g .\a148.ml
File ".\a148.ml", line 14, characters 2-180:
Warning S: this expression should have type unit.
File ".\a148.ml", line 22, characters 0-21:
Error: This expression has type unit but is here used with type int
```

So, looks like `if` expression cannot return value here (why?). I've added `let` binding

```
let k = 5
let l = 2
let m = 3
let n = 4
let d = 42

let rec total: int -> int -> int = fun i acc ->
  let x' = if i > d then
      acc
    else
      if (i mod k) == 0 || (i mod l) == 0 || (i mod m) == 0 || (i mod n) == 0 then
    total (i + 1) (acc + 1)
      else
    total (i + 1) acc;
    x'
print_int (total 1 0)
```

and it works, but raises another error:

```
File ".\a148.ml", line 23, characters 0-0:
Error: Syntax error
```

Line 23 is the next to `print_int` statement and empty, so it seems like compiler wants something else from me, but I don't know what.

**UPD:** ok, the working code:

```
let k = 5 in
let l = 2 in
let m = 3 in
let n = 4 in
let d = 42 in
let rec total i acc =
  if i > d then
    acc
  else
    if (i mod k) == 0 || (i mod l) == 0 || (i mod m) == 0 || (i mod n) == 0 then
      total (i + 1) (acc + 1)
    else
      total (i + 1) acc
in let x = total 1 0 in
print_int x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the misuse of semicolon (`;`).

Semicolon intends to be the sequence composition of two expressions. `S1 ; S2` means that the compiler expects `S1` to be `unit` type, computes `S1` and `S2` in that order and returns the result of `S2`.

Here you mistakenly use `;`, so OCaml expects the second `if...then...else` to return `unit` and wants you to provide one more expression. Removing `;` and adding necessary `in`(s) should make the function compile:

```
let k = 5 in
let l = 2 in
let m = 3 in
let n = 4 in
let d = 42 in

let rec total: int -> int -> int = fun i acc ->
  if i > d then
    acc
  else
    if (i mod k) == 0 || (i mod l) == 0 || (i mod m) == 0 || (i mod n) == 0 then
      total (i + 1) (acc + 1)
    else
      total (i + 1) acc
```

Regarding your second function, you should replace `;` by `in` to indicate that `x'` is used to compute the return value.

BTW, your `total` function looks weird since you use lambda expression in the function body. Explicit declaration is more readable:

```
let rec total i acc = 
   if i > d then
      acc
   else if i mod k = 0 || i mod l = 0 || i mod m = 0 || i mod n = 0 then
      total (i + 1) (acc + 1)
   else
      total (i + 1) acc
```

I have also changed reference equality `(==)` to structural equality `(=)` though there is no difference among them in integer.

Comment: It does not depends if semicolon presented or not, I tried different variations. If I remove semicolon in the first case, it raises an error `File ".\a148.ml", line 20, characters 6-11:
Error: This function is applied to too many arguments,
maybe you forgot a ';'`

Comment: Thanks, I've added lambda just to annotate the function type and check for errors. I should have read more about scopes, it works when I add the whole thing inside `in` for some reason.

Comment: It's obvious because you use `k`, `l`, `m`, `n` and `d` in `total`. I prefer to put them in `total`'s body if they are constant. Otherwise, they should become parameters.